How to derive conditional posterior predictive distribution from definition of posterior predictive distribution in bayesian regression?
In my situation, I have a set of data points:
$$ z_{0:n} = \\{ (x_0, y_0),\dots ,(x_{n-1}, y_{n-1}) \\} $$
I am trying to figure out how to derive the fully expanded form for the conditional posterior predictive distribution:
$$p(y|x, \mathcal{z}_{0:n})$$
from the definition of the posterior predictive distribution $(z=(x,y))$:
$$p(z|z_{0:n}) = \int p(z | \theta)p(\theta|z_{0:n}) d\theta$$
where
$$p(\theta|z_{0:n}) = \frac{p(z_{0:n}|\theta)p(\theta)}{p(z_{0:n})}$$
and
$$p(z_{0:n}) = \int p(z_{0:n}|\theta)p(\theta) d\theta$$.
Is it just repeated application of Baye's rule? as I am not sure how to "split" $x_{0:n}$ so it's on the other side of the conditional probability bar while $y_{0:n}$ remains.

This seems like a standard one-period forecasting problem.

Thank you @Durden , I am still unclear how they go about the decomposing that happens under the integral signs in that post.

Also @Durden would you say that this post perhaps answers this question meaning I should perhaps vote to close mine because it's a duplicate?

I do not see the difficulty since$$p(y|x,z_{0:n})\propto p(z|z_{0:n})$$
